# Apache Cassandra, how to estimate amount of work for repair

Tags: cassandra, nodetool, repair

We have a cluster conststing of 14 nodes in two datacenters, version 4.0.5. The database is pretty big and repair process takes pretty long time.
Is there any way to estimate the amount of changes for repair (in megabytes for example) without running actual repair?

I tried `nodetool info` and there is `Percent Repaired` metric, yes. But I'm not sure wether it coresponds to the value that I'm looking for or not...